# Google Sheets : Need help in automating the transpose option from columns to rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, unpivot

I am looking for an option in Google sheets where I can automate pivot/ transpose the values in columns to rows. something similar to power pivot in excel.

I have shared a sample and my requirement in the below google sheet link.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQk5CGiXwkJcUT63ghfx77QIw2ojXMkXJJHYMCAVKfjNu_GnVroOEQD-g_SGoZNVw0pvH6_YBFzdMGs/pubhtml

Appreciate your help here.

[image]

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another solution:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TOCOL(A2:A&"|"&B1:D1&"|"&B2:D),"|"),"where Col2<>''"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=reduce(tocol(,1),B2:index(D:D,match(,0/(A:A<>""))),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,hstack(index(A:A,row(c)),index(1:1,column(c)),c))))
```

[image]